# Display confirmation on beforeunload if user has written something somewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm searching for an event jquery which start when the user write something somewhere on the page. I found `.change()` but it doesn't work.

I tried to create a flag which become `true` when the user change the content of the page. After that, I use this flag to display the pop-up or not.

So I have this code for the variable and the event :

```
<script>
        var flagChange = false;
            $(window).change( function(){
                alert ('je suis ici');
                flagChange = true; 
            });
</script>
```

And I use this on this code :

```
<script> 
        if(flagChange)
        {
            $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
                return 'Les données non sauvegardées seront perdues. Voulez-vous vraiment quitter ?';
            });
        }
    </script>
```

But the pop up never displays.
Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    window.flag = false;
    $(document).on('keyup', function() {
        window.flag = true;
    });

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        if(window.flag) {
            return 'Les données non sauvegardées seront perdues. Voulez-vous vraiment quitter ?';
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is happening? What are you expecting? Do you have any error?

Comment: I found what was wrong. So, I tried to display your popup with your method, and it didn't work. It was just that, so I change "var popup = confirm..." with simply "return ..." and it works. But the rest is ok and now it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Lison: Edited accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

> $(window).change( function(){
>                   alert ('je suis ici');
>                   flagChange = true; 
>               });

It's incorrect. you need set **.change()** to every inputs.

Read more documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/change/